# How to conditionally show/hide properties of a page in EPiServer 9 CMS admin/backend

Tags: c#, dojo, episerver

I have spent a few days banging my head on this one.  There does not seem to be very many examples or resources online so I am hoping someone in the community can assist me.

I have a Page in EPiServer that has an int property that is tagged as a SelectOne (a drop down list).  I need to conditionally show/hide another property of the page type.  I came across [this](http://world.episerver.com/blogs/Duong-Nguyen/Dates/2014/1/Country-Region-drop-down-lists-in-All-properties-mode/) example online.  I can get it to work as written, but the second I try to modify it (with my very limited knowledge) it ceases to work.

This is my Page in EPiServer:

```
//'SitePageData' extends page data but is prolly irrelevant to this question
[ContentType]
public class LocationPage : SitePageData
{
    [CultureSpecific]
    [Display(
        Name = "Location Type",
        Description = "",
        GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
        Order = 10)]
    [SelectOne(SelectionFactoryType=typeof(LocationTypeSelectionFactory))]
    [UIHint("LocationType")]
    public virtual int LocationType { get; set; }

    [CultureSpecific]
    [Display(
        Name = "Address Key",
        Description = "",
        GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
        Order = 20)]
    public virtual string AddressKey { get; set; }

    //........Rest of class properties here.......
}
```

This is my Editor Descriptor:

```
[EditorDescriptorRegistration(TargetType=typeof(string), UIHint="LocationType")]
public class LocationTypeEditorDescriptor : EditorDescriptor
{
    public override void ModifyMetadata(EPiServer.Shell.ObjectEditing.ExtendedMetadata metadata, IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
    {
        ClientEditingClass = "alloy/LocationType";
        base.ModifyMetadata(metadata, attributes);
    }
}
```

This is my JS file (LocationType.js) located in the /ClientResources/Scripts/ folder

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/_base/lang",

    "epi/shell/layout/SimpleContainer"
],
function (
    declare,
    lang,

    SimpleContainer
) {

        return declare([SimpleContainer], {
            addChild: function (child) {
                // Summar: Add a widget to the container
                this.inherited(arguments);
                if (child.name.indexOf("locationtype") >= 0) {
                    this.own(child.on("change", lang.hitch(this, this._updateDropdown)));
            },

            _updateDropdown: function (obj) {
                console.log(obj.value);
            } 
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see I am just trying to register an on change event (like in the linked example above).  I assume this is the key functionality I would need to then selectively hide the "AddressKey" field.  As you can see I haven't tackled the first problem yet.

I think one of my problems is I am potentially extending the wrong container type in dojo.  I don't know enough to know for sure however.

Has anyone implemented a similar functionality in EPiServer?  Is this just a super simple Dojo question?

I appreciate any and all help, thanks in advance !

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to only support this in the DOPE-editor?

Comment: Do you also have a widget template where the dropdown is declared?